# Unable to login to org after registering my domain and deploying it to users

Tags: lightning, login-errors, mydomain

For previewing a lightning app I started with registering for my domain and deploying it to users. 
After this when everytime I try to preview the lightning app it kicks me back to the login page

What is this issue ?

Comment: What exactly are you doing for `preview the lightning app`? please share the steps that you are taking and your code

Comment: Try changing the browser/IP. Seems the weird answer, however this happened to me as well. I was able to login to my org thr my mobile, however not with existing browser.